Release Elastic IP option not appearing as action
I have just created an ec2 instance in order to work on a certification course . I have associated to the instance an elastic IP as exercise . I have dissasociated the elastic IP from the EC2 instance, but now, when I go to elastic IP's dashboard, and try to release the elastic ip's, I can´t see the action "Release elastic IP`s" , even that the elastic IP is dissasociated from the EC2 instance . How can I release the elastic IP ? Is it a matter of permissions ? I have admin access to the IAM account .


In English, the second menu option says "Release Elastic IP addresses".

Thanks John . As simple as that . I have changed the language to Eng_UK . For me it will be far easier .
